# Laravel Auth facade not working after changing the tenant database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, multi-tenant, laravel-authentication

When I am changing the database dynamically during login process, Auth facade do not understand it and always taking the user from default database.
 All things are working except Auth facade.
This is the function for changing the tenant db

```
function setDBConnection($params){
    config(['database.connections.tenant' => [
        'driver'   => $params['driver'],
        'host'     => $params['host'],
        'database' => $params['database'],
        'username' => $params['username'],
        'password' => $params['password'],
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
    ]]);
    DB::reconnect('tenant');
}
```

and I have in my tenant models

```
protected $connection = 'tenant';
```

also I am using a middleware for keeping connection.
Please help me out, thank you very much!